# Change Peer signing digest from s_server

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have been testing a TLS connection on localhost with s_server and s_client.
The problem that I have is that on the client side I read the following information:

Peer signing digest: SHA512

I want to be able to change the signing digest with SHA256 but I don't find the correct argument in s_server to do that.

```
openssl s_server -accept 4433 -cert cert.pem -key key.pem  -Verify 1 -msg -debug -cipher eNULL:aRSA
verify depth is 1, must return a certificate
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone finds this question. I found the two arguments I was missing for RSA signing:

On server side: -sigalgs RSA+SHA256
On client side: -client_sigalgs RSA+SHA256